# Use expression in window function that references columns from the current row

Tags: sql-server, window-functions, database-agnostic

Suppose I have the following query that uses window function:

```
SELECT id
     , var
     , num
     , SUM(var * num) OVER (ORDER BY id ROWS BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS calc
FROM (VALUES
    (1, 0.1, 7),
    (2, 0.7, 1),
    (3, 0.3, 9),
    (4, 0.9, 5),
    (5, 0.5, 3)
) AS t(id, var, num)
```

And the following result:

```
id | var | num | calc | explanation
1  | 0.1 | 7   | 0.7  | 0.1*7
2  | 0.7 | 1   | 1.4  | 0.1*7 + 0.7*1
3  | 0.3 | 9   | 4.1  | 0.1*7 + 0.7*1 + 0.3*9
4  | 0.9 | 5   | 7.9  | 0.7*1 + 0.3*9 + 0.9*5
5  | 0.5 | 3   | 8.7  | 0.3*9 + 0.9*5 + 0.5*3
```

Is is possible to reference the `var` column *from the outside* inside the `SUM() OVER ()`? For example:

```
id | var | num | calc | sum of f(r.var, w.var, w.num)
1  | 0.1 | 7   | ...  | iif(0.1<=0.1,0.1,0.1)*7
2  | 0.7 | 1   | ...  | iif(0.7<=0.1,0.7,0.1)*7 + iif(0.7<=0.7,0.7,0.7)*1
3  | 0.3 | 9   | ...  | iif(0.3<=0.1,0.3,0.1)*7 + iif(0.3<=0.7,0.3,0.7)*1 + iif(0.3<=0.3,0.3,0.3)*9
4  | 0.9 | 5   | ...  | iif(0.9<=0.7,0.9,0.7)*1 + iif(0.9<=0.3,0.9,0.3)*9 + iif(0.9<=0.9,0.9,0.9)*5
5  | 0.5 | 3   | ...  | iif(0.5<=0.3,0.5,0.3)*9 + iif(0.5<=0.9,0.5,0.9)*5 + iif(0.5<=0.5,0.5,0.5)*3
```

Basically I want to calculate running sum of an expression that references `var` column in the current row and `var` column in the current window. `iif` and multiplication is just an example.

The solution should work in SQL Server but generic answer would be best.

[Here is a db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=be72951d52e6aae4343e3fd5745dc8f1) where I was able to achieve the result with correlated queries but I want to use window functions.

Comment: It could be arbitrary number of rows e.g. 100 or there could be no `ROWS BETWEEN` at all. The values do not matter, one can post the output that proves that `SUM` was calculated for each row in window based on the rows inside and outside the window.

Comment: This is interesting problem. Definitely not easy when the window size is arbitrary and not just 3 rows.

Comment: Despite you calling it a "running sum" it is in no sense a running sum because you aren't just adding something to the previous total

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for ?

```
create table #t(id int, vars decimal(3,1), num int)
insert into #t VALUES
    (1, 0.1, 7),
    (2, 0.7, 1),
    (3, 0.3, 9),
    (4, 0.9, 5),
    (5, 0.5, 3)


;With CTE as
(
select
      t.id
     ,t.vars
     ,t.num
     ,isnull(lag(vars ,1) OVER (ORDER BY id ),0) AS vars1
     ,isnull(lag(vars ,2) OVER (ORDER BY id ),0) AS vars2
     ,isnull(lag(num ,1) OVER (ORDER BY id ),0) AS num1
     ,isnull(lag(num ,2) OVER (ORDER BY id ),0) AS num2
FROM  #t t
)

select * 
,iif(vars<=0.1,vars,vars2)*num2 + 
iif(vars<=vars1,vars,vars1)*num1 + 
iif(vars<=vars,vars,vars)*num
from CTE

drop table #t
```

Comment: I cannot hard code 1 and 2... the size of window could be anything... even unbounded.

Comment: @SalmanA, do you mean to say my output is correct ?You should explain the biz. reuirement for  size of window or unbounded.How do I understand size of window ?

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a way to solve this using window functions, so here is a method that uses a triangular self-join.

Tested in [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/GNHAq2Sm)

```
WITH
  tt (id, var, num, rn) AS
  ( SELECT id, var, num,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY id) AS rn
    FROM 
    ( VALUES
      (1, 0.1, 7),
      (2, 0.7, 1),
      (3, 0.3, 9),
      (4, 0.9, 5),
      (5, 0.5, 3)
    ) AS t (id, var, num)
  )
SELECT tt.id,
       tt.var,
       tt.num,
       SUM( LEAST(tt.var, ti.var) * ti.num ) AS calc
    -- SUM( CASE WHEN tt.var < ti.var THEN tt.var ELSE ti.var END
    --      * ti.num ) AS calc
FROM tt JOIN tt AS ti
     ON  ti.rn >= tt.rn -2    -- BETWEEN 2 PRECEDING
     AND ti.rn <= tt.rn +0    -- AND CURRENT ROW
GROUP BY tt.rn, tt.id, tt.var, tt.num ;
```

The `LEAST()` function is available only in SQL Server 2022, so for older versions, the `CASE` expression should be used instead.